# Kotlin Create Checkbox and Remove Checkbox Programatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am able to add in checkbox dynamically when I tick an existing checkbox, however I can't seem to remove the new checkbox when I untick the existing checkbox.

```
baseCheckBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.newLinearLayout) as LinearLayout

            if(baseCheckBox.isChecked){



                val newBox= CheckBox(this)

                newBox.text = "New CheckBox"
                newBox.isChecked = true
                linearLayout.addView(newBox)

            }

            else{
                val tempLayout = findViewById(1) as LinearLayout

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is by storing the reference to newly created `Checkbox` in the tag of `baseCheckBox`, so you can get it and remove it:

```
baseCheckBox.setOnClickListener{
    val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.newLinearLayout)

    if (baseCheckBox.isChecked) {
        val newBox = CheckBox(this)
        newBox.text = "New CheckBox"
        newBox.isChecked = true
        linearLayout.addView(newBox)
        baseCheckBox.setTag(newBox)
    } else {
        try {
            val cb = baseCheckBox.tag as CheckBox
            linearLayout.removeView(cb)
            baseCheckBox.tag = null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible for me to add an id? It is because I want to get the the value to present it on toast. And is it possible to display multiple checkboxes i.e set multiple tags?

Comment: Yes you can with `setId(integer number)` but the problem is that you would not know if it is unique when you try to find it. With the above code you can get a reference to the created checkbox by getting it from the `baseCheckBox`'s tag, just like I did: `val cb = baseCheckBox.tag as CheckBox`

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding another checkbox and set another tag on the same baseCheckBox, howeveer it doesn't seem to remove it. Does the tag only work once?

Comment: Yes, the tag holds one reference.